# rails 4 modeling many to many polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-modeling, polymorphic-associations

I'm struggling with first step on "how to model the relationship"?  I've following few models,

```
class CarMake  
end  

class Region  
end  

Class CarModel  
end
```

The relation is 'Car Maker' has many models belongs to zero or more regions. For e.g. Let's say that Honda has a 'Civic' model in North America and Asia. Also Honda has 'CivicMini' only in Europe. What would be the best way to model these relations? Is it like each CarModel belongs to a CarMaker through Region?

Also there are few other models who uses this relation,

### Customer

```
class Customer  
  has_many :cars   
end
```

### This car references to all the attributes like CarMake,CarModel,Region, but how (Do I need another class to store these attributes and reference it here in 'Car'?)

```
class Car  
  belongs_to :customer  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Car class define a polymorphic interface

```
belongs_to :car_type(interface name change according to you), polymorphic: true
```

In CarMaker class

```
has_many :cars, as: :car_type
```

In CarModel class

```
has_many :cars, as: :car_type
```

In Region class

```
has_many :cars, as: :car_type
```

And whenever you store record in cars table ....store the object type that would be (CarMaker, CarModel, Region) and id

Comment: Rubyist,  Thanks for the reply. Since, I never used this interface before, it raises a question for me, i.e. how do you map each of those classes to its own table including customer?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
class Maker
   has_many :models
end

class Model
   has_many :regions
   belongs_to :maker
end

class Region
  belongs_to :model
end

class Car
  has_one :model
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer
  has_many :cars
end
```

So in this case, a customer could have multiple cars that are the same or different models, and the model can have many different regions and belongs to a maker.

Does this work for your use case?